# Can I check if people are viewing/using my Magento store instantly?

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2

I realise I can use Google Analytics to check this retrospectively, but it would be great if I could instantly see how many people are visiting our Magento store at any given moment, and ideally the page/product they are viewing.  Our old osCommerce site had this in the tools menu, and it was very interesting as well as useful, especially if we were about to take the site offline for a few minutes. Not sure if it matters, but we are using the Ultimo theme.  Any advice gratefully received!

Comment: Did you check "Online Customers" menu item in admin. It is available under "Customer" menu item.

Comment: You can view this, in real time, in google analytics.

Comment: Many thanks, will try both!  Had no idea Google Analytics showed real-time info :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Customer->Online Customers found in the admin navigation[image: Online Customers Magento]